# Need clarification on when to use quotes and when not to in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript following the courses from codecademy.com.  Recently they introduced bracket notation (as opposed to the simpler dot notation).  I understand there are advantages because you can reference things that you can't reference using dot notation.  However I don't understand why I'm supposed to use quotes in certain circumstances.

For example:

```
var suitcase = {
    shorts: "purple"
};
if (suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")) {
    console.log(suitcase.shorts);
}
```

Why does shorts need quotes around it in the line `if (suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")) {`?  I'm used to quotes designating something as a string.  shorts is a property of the suitcase object so I would think it would be referenced without quotes.  So far I've been doing well understanding the rules of JavaScript but this wasn't clearly explained so I find myself confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects' properties' names are just strings. You can always refer to a property by a string name like `a["b"]`. The one exception is when you use a `.`. In that case, `a.b` is a property. This is equivalent to `a["b"]`. In all other cases, use strings to refer to property names.

`hasOwnProperty` is a normal method. If you had passed in `shorts` rather than `"shorts"`, JS would have treated `shorts` as a variable.

Comment: They never made it clear before that parameter names were treated as strings.  Considering they act like variables that can be reassigned I'm not sure why that is but I think this is the missing link that I wasn't understanding hopefully. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
var suitcase = {
    shorts: 'purple',
    shorts: purple
}
```

yes, it's assigning to 'shorts' twice. But  the first line, `'purple'` is assigning a STRING whose value is `purple` to the shorts object key. The second line, is assigning a VARIABLE named `purple`, which has not yet been defined.

Context is everything in Javascript. There's no need to quote the `shorts` portion, because the JS interpreter knows you'r defining an object key there. But it's NOT smart enough to decide if `purple` should be a string representing a color, or a variable whose name happens to be `purple`. That's why there's quotes - to provide the necessary context.

Ditto for the `hasOwnProperty`. If shorts isn't quoted, then it's treated as an undefined variable. if it IS quoted, then it's a string.

Comment: I've never seen the single quotes before that you put around the first 'purple'.  Is that the same as "purple"?  I've also never heard the name object key, is that the same as a parameter?

Comment: Yeah, you can use single or double quotes for strings. This is convenient if you want to have a string containing one or the other: `'"abc"'` is much nicer than `"\"abc\""`, and they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is the same as:

```
    suitcase = new Object();  
    suitcase.shorts = 'purple';
    suitcase.hasOwnProperty('shorts');   //returns true
```

Always remember that arguments/parameter in javascript not enclosed in `qoutes` is variable. Not just javascript actually, all languages. Do not confuse yourself with variables.

Javascript expects a variable `shorts`.

```
    var shorts = 'shorts';
    suitcase.hasOwnProperty(shorts);   //returns true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

the `hasOwnProperty()` function needs the name of the property you want to check for.  Therefore it needs to be passed in as a string.  If you leave off the quotes then javascript will assume you're passing a variable containing the property name.

Comment: So a parameter name isn't considered a variable?  I mean it's underneath an object and can be constantly reassigned.  How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Without the quotes javascript is going to interpret shorts as an object and since shorts is undefined you get. The hasOwnProperty function is looking for a property name of type string.

```
ReferenceError: shorts is not defined
```

so

```
suitcase.shorts
```

returns "purple"

```
shorts !== suitcase.shorts
```

shorts is not the same object as suitcase.shorts, in fact it is not even an object until you declare it.

```
shorts = "brown"
```

This sets the value of shorts to "brown", but suitcase.shorts is still "purple"

I hope this clears that up.

Comment: When you enter a variable you don't quote it, so only strings and paramaters need quotes?  I'm trying to understand the underlying rules here.  How is it not defined?  Shorts is a parameter under the object.  I guess I'm not understanding what makes it defined or not defined.